# Do PCRE control verbs like (*SKIP) move the bumpalong when inside a DEFINEd group?

Tags: recursion, pcre

I typically skip unwanted text by using `(*SKIP)(*F)` in my outer-most group:

```
/(?x)
# Match "quoted text" except when immediately followed by colon:
"(?>[^\\"]+|\\(?s:.))*"[:](*SKIP)(*F)|
"(?>[^\\"]+|\\(?s:.))*"
/
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/zMgykW/1)

When I move `(*SKIP)(*F)` into a group, this acts differently:

```
/(?x)
(?&Text)
(?(DEFINE)
 # Match "quoted text" except when immediately followed by colon:
 (?<Text>
  "(?>[^\\"]+|\\(?s:.))*":(*SKIP)(*F)
 |"(?>[^\\"]+|\\(?s:.))*"
 )
)/
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/zMgykW/2)

In the first example, the `(*SKIP)(*F)` moves the bumpalong to the point in the string after the colon (according to the regex debugger) before trying again. In the second example, the bumpalong appears to only move onto the next character in the string.

What causes this logic to differ?

### Update:

Moving the `(*SKIP)(*F)` block into a DEFINE group appears to work as expected in perl 5.24. It moves the bumpalong the same as if `(*SKIP)(*F)` were encountered in the outer-most group.

Could this be a bug in the PCRE/PCRE2 implementation?

Comment: This is noted in PCRE2 documentation: "In PCRE2, if any of the backtracking control verbs are used in a group that is called as a subroutine (whether or not recursively), their effect is confined to that group; it does not extend to the surrounding pattern. This is not always the case in Perl. In particular, if (*THEN) is present in a group that is called as a subroutine, its action is limited to that group, even if the group does not contain any | characters. Note that such groups are processed as anchored at the point where they are tested" http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2compat.html

Comment: Very interesting. @Michail: you should post an answer.